# Unable to run browserstack-cypress command

Tags: javascript, cypress, browserstack

I try installed 'browserstack-cli' using npm however when i try to execute command 'browserstack-cypress run' or npm run browserstack => I'm getting following error. JSON files are correct. What can be the issue?
[image]

'browserstack-cypress run' or npm run browserstack not working

Comment: try 'npm install -g browserstack-cypress-cli'

Comment: Looks like you may be using an older version of browserstack-cypress cli that uses cypress.json. The newer versions use cypress.config.js or cypress.config.ts.

Comment: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration